# Fifa 17 Replay celebration

Tags: fifa-17

The replay is cut out seconds after a goal is scored and every time it cuts right when the player will make the special celebration.

Is there any way to replay celebrations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think so, it was a problem present on Fifa 15 too (if I recall correctly).

The only solution I can give you is to celebrate right after scoring pressing any button, because sometimes the player starts running towards the corner flag or something else delaying the celebration.